# How do I rethrow errors thrown by functions I'm calling?

Tags: swift

I've got a generic function called getResponse that can fail at 3 points and throws appropriate errors at each point.

When I call this function from another function I'd like to rethrow whatever error it threw if that occurs, but I'm not sure how to do that in swift.

Here's the generic function:

```
private static func getResponse<T: Codable>(urlComponents: URLComponents, responseType: T.Type) async throws -> T {
    guard let url = urlComponents.url else {
        throw VVError.URLCouldNotBeCreated
    }


    guard let (data, _) = try? await URLSession.shared.data(from: url) else {
        throw VVError.DataCouldNotBeRetrieved
    }

    
    guard let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data) else {
        throw VVError.JSONDataCouldNotBeDecoded
    }

    return response
}
```

I call it from this function:

```
static func getWorkoutList(hashString: String) async throws -> WorkoutListResponse {
    var urlComponents = getURLComponents()
    urlComponents.path = "/Workout/WorkoutList"
    urlComponents.queryItems = [
        URLQueryItem(name: "hashString", value: hashString)
    ]

    guard let workoutListResponse = try? await getResponse(urlComponents: urlComponents, responseType: WorkoutListResponse.self) else {
        throw VVError.DataCouldNotBeRetrieved // I don't want to throw this error, I want to throw whatever error getResponse threw.
    }

    return workoutListResponse
}
```

Instead of throwing `VVError.DataCouldNotBeRetrieved` in the `guard let`, I'd prefer to rethrow whatever error `getResponse` threw.

How can I do that?

Comment: Replace `try?` with a `try` inside a do/catch if you want to re-throw the error otherwise just use `try`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
guard let workoutListResponse = try? await getResponse(urlComponents: urlComponents, responseType: WorkoutListResponse.self) else {
    throw VVError.DataCouldNotBeRetrieved // I don't want to throw this error, I want to throw whatever error getResponse threw.
}
```

to:

```
let workoutListResponse = try await getResponse(urlComponents: urlComponents, responseType: WorkoutListResponse.self)
```

If the `try` fails due to an error the error will be propagated by the enclosing function.